# Regex trying to match everything before backslash / not working

Tags: regex, linux

I am  attempting to use regex to match everything before the /, but when i try the following I get nothing outputted. I double checked my regex and seems okay, but not sure why it isn't working..

```
[user@user my_dir]$ tar -tf abc_de123_01.02.03.4.tgz | grep -m1 /
abc_de123_01.02.03.4/abcde.ini
[user@user my_dir]$ tar -tf abc_de123_01.02.03.4.tgz | grep -m1 .*\/
[user@user my_dir]$ tar -tf abc_de123_01.02.03.4.tgz | grep -m1 /$

expected output:
abc_de123_01.02.03.4/
```

Comment: Grep by default works on line wise operations. If you need only part of the string in a line you might use cut instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems here.

- One problem is that `*` has a special meaning to your shell; if you run `echo grep -m1 .*\/`, you'll see that your shell is expanding `.*\/` in a way you don't expect.
- One problem is that grep prints matching *lines* by default. If you want it to print just the matching *part* of a line, you need the `-o` flag.
- One problem that's not actually breaking your command, but that you should nonetheless fix, is that your shell uses `\` as a quoting (escape) character, so `\/` actually means just `/`. (The reason this doesn't break anything is that `/` isn't special to grep anyway, so you didn't actually need the `\` for anything.)

So:

```
grep -m1 -o '.*/'
```

which finds the first line containing `/`, and prints everything up through the last `/` on that line.

Incidentally, `/` is not a *backslash*, but simply a *slash* (or sometimes *forward slash*). A *backslash* is `\`.

Answer (score 0):

Grep by default works on line wise operations. If you need only part of the string in all the lines you might use cut instead.

```
tar -tf abc_de123_01.02.03.4.tgz | cut -d'/' -f1
```

Now if you need only the first part of the first match sed come in hand:

```
tar -tf abc_de123_01.02.03.4.tgz | sed "1q;d" | cut -d'/' -f1
```